# Why does diode keep conducting even after voltage across it is negative

Tags: power-electronics, converter, bridge-rectifier, scr

consider single phase two pulse semiconverter asymmetric configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXnw19.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the high value of inductance L1.

Let `a` be trigger angle of SCR, which is greater than `t = arcsin(E/Vs)`. Now the SCR will work from `a` to `pi-t` and maybe beyond if current does not fall below holding current. But would not the diode `D2` turn off after `pi-t` because voltage falls below zero?

Why does using a high value of inductance allows current to flow in `D2` beyond `pi-t` and upto `pi+a` ? Does the emf `E` play no role in switching off the diode?

What actually happens after `pi-t` to `pi+a`? I assume that D3 cannot start conducting before `pi+t` and `SCR4` cannot start conducting before `pi+a`. So where does the inductor current go?

Comment: Why do you think it behaves this way?

Comment: If you can imagine it, you might simulate it. Add drivers. https://tinyurl.com/y3nhotco

Comment: ANother thing to consider is the diode's "reverse recovery time". The 1N4148 is pretty fast so that's probably not an issue here; if you were to replace it with 1N4001, that would be a different matter.

Comment: I have to wonder whether 100 kilo-Henries is a realistic value for a high-power inductor. Certainly not for a small one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inductor's stored magnetic energy will try and keep current flowing through both itself and D2 by generating sufficient back-emf to forward bias D2. That's pretty much what an inductor will do in this situation.

> *Why does diode keep conducting even after voltage across it is
> negative*

You might think that it's negative but, until the inductor has pretty-much got rid of most of its stored energy, the diode will be kept forward biased (like it or not).

Comment: I feel this is the correct reason! Thank you! Would you mind checking my proposed output voltage across load: https://imgur.com/a/Efr8rjP output voltage is shown in green

Comment: I'm not seeing a relation to the schematic in your question. The best way is to simulate the waveform and see the effect of the inductor.

Answer (score 2):

From KVL,
$$
R I + L \frac{dI}{dt} + E = V_s \sin(\omega t) \tag{1}
$$
for \$a/\omega \le t \le (\pi + a)/\omega\$ and the general solution of eq. 1 is
$$
I(t) = I_0 e^{-\frac{R}{L}t} + \frac{V_s}{R^2 + (\omega L)^2} (R \sin (\omega t) - \omega L \cos (\omega t)) - \frac{E}{R}. \tag{2}
$$
At steady state, \$I\$ at the beginning and end of cycles are same, i.e. cyclic condition;
$$
I\left(\frac{a}{\omega}\right) = I\left(\frac{\pi + a}{\omega}\right) \tag{3}.
$$
By solving eq. 3, we can get \$I_0\$ and the particular solution of eq. 1.

If \$I(t) > 0\$ for any \$t\$, the circuit is working in Continuous Conduction Mode (CCM) and all diodes are conducting current all the time.
Otherwise, Discontinuous Conduction Mode (DCM) and diodes block the current for a period in a cycle.
For DCM, eq. 3 is not applicable and initial condition \$I(a/\omega)=0\$ is used instead.

It is a typical case which can be found in a lot of power electronics books.